# Check / Compare NSError Code in CloudKit?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, cloudkit, nserror

I guess it is basic, but still .. how can I check whether I get a `ZoneBusy` error?

```
if error.code == CKErrorCode.ZoneBusy { // <- compiler says can't use '==', then what?
```

[image]

Reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CloudKit_constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CKErrorCode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you are missing `.rawValue`.

So it should be:

`CKErrorCode.ZoneBusy.rawValue`